# who to avoid user control from passing link to the _controltemplates/15/ folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i'm developing a user control to be embedded inside my master page, when i finished and this user control is well done, by the way i made a  Anchor inside this user control when i click this anchor bring me inside  /_controltemplates/15/ where User control are deployed inside sharepoint:
i got this link : myserver:port/_controltemplates/15/www.google.com
i want www.google.com not the folder.
any help please.

this is my user control:

```
<table style="background-color: orange;">
    <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="www.google.com" runat="server">go to google</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `http:` to the link:

```
<table style="background-color: orange;">
    <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" runat="server">go to google</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```